# Ftps server doesn't work properly using kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, port, ftps, vsftpd

i have a problem with ftps-filezilla and Kubernetes for weeks.

**CONTEXT** :

I have a school project with Kubernetes and ftps.
I need to create a ftps server in kubernetes in the port 21, and it needs to run on alpine linux.
So i create an image of my ftps-alpine server using a docker container.
I test it, if it work properly on it own :
Using `docker run --name test-alpine -itp 21:21 test_alpine`
I have this output in filezilla :

```
    Status: Connecting to 192.168.99.100:21…
    Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message…
    Status: Initializing TLS…
    Status: Verifying certificate…
    Status: TLS connection established.
    Status: Logged in
    Status: Retrieving directory listing…
    Status: Calculating timezone offset of server…
    Status: Timezone offset of server is 0 seconds.
    Status: Directory listing of “/” successful
```

It work successfully, filezilla see the file that is within my ftps directory
I am good for now(work on active mode).

**PROBLEM** :

So what i wanted, was to use my image in my kubernetes cluster(I use Minikube).
When i connect my docker image to an ingress-service-deployment in kubernetes I have that :

```
    Status: Connecting to 192.168.99.100:30894…
    Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message…
    Status: Initializing TLS…
    Status: Verifying certificate…
    Status: TLS connection established.
    Status: Logged in
    Status: Retrieving directory listing…
    Command:    PWD
    Response:   257 “/” is the current directory
    Command:    TYPE I
    Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
    Command:    PORT 192,168,99,1,227,247
    Response:   500 Illegal PORT command.
    Command:    PASV
    Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (172,17,0,5,117,69).
    Command:    LIST
    Error:  The data connection could not be established: EHOSTUNREACH - No route to host
    Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
    Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

**SETUP** :

```
ingress.yaml :

    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
    annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    namespace: default
    name: ingress-controller
    spec:
    backend:
    serviceName: my-nginx
    servicePort: 80
    backend:
    serviceName: ftps-alpine
    servicePort: 21

ftps-alpine.yml :

    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
    name: ftps-alpine
    labels:
    run: ftps-alpine
    spec:
    type: NodePort
    ports:

    port: 21
    targetPort: 21
    protocol: TCP
    name: ftp21
    port: 20
    targetPort: 20
    protocol: TCP
    name: ftp20
    selector:
    run: ftps-alpine
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
    name: ftps-alpine
    spec:
    selector:
    matchLabels:
    run: ftps-alpine
    replicas: 1
    template:
    metadata:
    labels:
    run: ftps-alpine
    spec:
    - name: ftps-alpine
    image: test_alpine
    imagePullPolicy: Never
    ports:
    - containerPort: 21
    - containerPort: 20
```

**WHAT DID I TRY** :

- When i see the error message : Error: The data connection could not
  be established: EHOSTUNREACH - No route to host google it and i see
  this message :
  [FTP in passive mode : EHOSTUNREACH - No route to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31001017/ftp-in-passive-mode-ehostunreach-no-route-to-host)
  . And i already run my ftps server in active mode.
- Change vsftpd.conf file and my service:

```
vsftpd.conf :

    seccomp_sandbox=NO
    pasv_promiscuous=NO
    listen=NO
    listen_ipv6=YES
    anonymous_enable=NO
    local_enable=YES
    write_enable=YES
    local_umask=022
    dirmessage_enable=YES
    use_localtime=YES
    xferlog_enable=YES
    connect_from_port_20=YES
    chroot_local_user=YES
    #secure_chroot_dir=/vsftpd/empty
    pam_service_name=vsftpd
    pasv_enable=YES
    pasv_min_port=30020
    pasv_max_port=30021
    user_sub_token=$USER
    local_root=/home/$USER/ftp
    userlist_enable=YES
    userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
    userlist_deny=NO
    rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
    rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
    ssl_enable=YES
    allow_anon_ssl=NO
    force_local_data_ssl=YES
    force_local_logins_ssl=YES
    ssl_tlsv1=YES
    ssl_sslv2=NO
    ssl_sslv3=NO
    allow_writeable_chroot=YES
    #listen_port=21
```

I did change my the nodeport of my kubernetes to 30020 and 30021 and i add them to containers ports.
I change the pasv min port and max port.
I add the pasv_adress of my minikube ip.
Nothing work .

**Question** :

How can i have the successfully first message but for my kubernetes cluster ?

If you have any questions to clarify, no problem.

**UPDATE** :

Thanks to coderanger, i have advance and there is this problem :

```
Status: Connecting to 192.168.99.100:30894...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,99,100,178,35).
Command:    LIST
Error:  The data connection could not be established: ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works with the following change:

```
apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: ftps-alpine
      labels:
        run: ftps-alpine
    spec:
      type: NodePort
      ports:
      - port: 21
        targetPort: 21
        nodePort: 30025
        protocol: TCP
        name: ftp21
      - port: 20
        targetPort: 20
        protocol: TCP
        nodePort: 30026
        name: ftp20
      - port: 30020
        targetPort: 30020
        nodePort: 30020
        protocol: TCP
        name: ftp30020
      - port: 30021
        targetPort: 30021
        nodePort: 30021
        protocol: TCP
        name: ftp30021
      selector:
        run: ftps-alpine
    ---

    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: ftps-alpine
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          run: ftps-alpine
      replicas: 1
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            run: ftps-alpine
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: ftps-alpine
            image: test_alpine
            imagePullPolicy: Never
            ports:
            - containerPort: 21
            - containerPort: 20
            - containerPort: 30020
            - containerPort: 30021
```

and for the vsftpd.conf :

```
seccomp_sandbox=NO
pasv_promiscuous=NO
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
#secure_chroot_dir=/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=30020
pasv_max_port=30021
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/home/$USER/ftp
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
userlist_deny=NO
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
#listen_port=21
pasv_address=#minikube_ip#
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason for 2 service objects of type `NodePort` with names of `ftp30021` and `ftp30020`?

Comment: No, i choose the names randomly. I could have name them differently.

Comment: What I wanted to ask about was the existence of this 2x`NodePorts` on ports `30020` and `30021`. Are they necessary? Did you try to do it without them as you are using active mode?

Comment: yes, i am using pasv mode now, in my cluster. and i did try to remove the 2 port in my deployment and it doesn't work. i will try to simplify if possible.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fix your passive port range to actually be port 20 like you set in service:

```
pasv_min_port=20
pasv_max_port=20
```

And then you need to override the `pasv_address` to match whatever IP the user should be connecting to, pick one of your node IPs.

Comment: thanks for the help, i made some change in my vsftpd file : pasv_min and max to 20 and pasv_adress=my_minikuke_ip but there is that : Command: PASV
Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (172,17,0,6,117,69).
Command: LIST
Error: The data connection could not be established: EHOSTUNREACH - No route to host

Comment: `pasv_address=192.168.99.100`.

Comment: `227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,99,100,4,37)`